# Indexes with custom collations in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, indexing, sql-order-by, collation

Assuming I have a schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE abc(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  txt TEXT
);

CREATE INDEX "txtCS" ON "abc"("txt" COLLATE MY_CUSTOM_SORT);
```

**when will sqlite use my index on `txt` ?**

because I ran:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY txt COLLATE MY_CUSTOM_SORT DESC ...
```

and it tells me that it scans the table, twice, using the `txtCS` index (It doesn't search like I expected.)

`MY_CUSTOM_SORT` is my own sorting function that I hooked with `sqliteCreateCollation`. I just need that index for some queries that involve special ordering and I want them to be fast

Comment: I get a single entry `SCAN TABLE abc USING COVERING INDEX txtCS`, which is perfectly fine. What is that `...`? Which SQLite version?

Comment: That's what I get too. But why it is SCAN and not SEARCH?

Comment: I assume, in order to utilize custom SQL index, MY_CUSTOM_SORT function should be explicitly declared as SQLITE_DETERMINISTIC - please see [Indexes On Expressions, Restrictions section](https://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html) for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html), SEARCH means that the database tries to look up some particular record(s) with specific values, while SCAN means that the database goes through the entire table.
This query returns all records, so the most efficient operation is a SCAN.

Either operation can be sped up with an index.
(In a SCAN, the database just goes through all index entries in order.)